# Ubuntu Apache Configuration - Proxy

Tags: wordpress, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, moodle

I have a Linux/Ubuntu Virtual Machine that uses 22.04LTS

I have a website hosted in WP Engine, which is running a ProxyPass from an NGINX server to this Ubuntu VM.

Whenever a user visits the following address https://domain-name.com/directory-name/ it does a ProxyPass to http://custom-domain-name.com and it appears in the browser address bar as https://domain-name.com/directory-name/

Apparently the WP Engine system will not allow the passing with domain and directory. Hence the format doesn't match 100%.

The problem I need assistance with is configuring this server when the signal arrives for http://custom-domain-name.com I need it to target http://custom-domain-name.com/directory-name/
This is where the application Moodle LMS configuration file is located.

This is where the application which runs on this virtual machine is located.

I tried adjusting the conf file to target the directory specifically but it then goes into an endless loop.

I can target the root directory and confirm that PHP is executing correctly as expected, but not the application.

Comment: People can help you better if you share your domain.conf

Comment: this question is better asked here https://askubuntu.com or here https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

in moodle's config.php you have this value :

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://domain-name.com/moodle';
```

have you checked it points to the custom address and not the default one? If it points toward the https://domain-name.com/directory-name/ this situation is normal. You should make it

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://custom-domain-name.com';
```

I'll edit this message here to complement what i was saying in comment:
Still in the config file you can find several useful configuration which are commented :

```
// It is possible to add extra themes directory stored outside of  $CFG->dirroot.
// This local directory does not have to be accessible from internet.
//
//     $CFG->themedir = '/location/of/extra/themes';
//  
// It is possible to specify different cache and temp directories, use local fast filesystem
// for normal web servers. Server clusters MUST use shared filesystem for cachedir!
// Localcachedir is intended for server clusters, it does not have to be shared by cluster nodes.
// The directories must not be accessible via web.
//
//     $CFG->tempdir = '/var/www/moodle/temp';        // Directory MUST BE SHARED by all cluster nodes.
//     $CFG->cachedir = '/var/www/moodle/cache';      // Directory MUST BE SHARED by all cluster nodes, locking required.
//     $CFG->localcachedir = '/var/local/cache';      // Intended for local node caching.
//     $CFG->localrequestdir = '/tmp';                // Intended for local only temporary files. The defaults uses sys_get_temp_dir().
```

This here starts on line 482 on my config file (but it may vary depending on your version)

In older version, (4.3 here), there's also a $CFG->dirroot=""; to specify. If it isn't present in your file, you may want to try adding it below the wwwroot.
For peace of mind don't forget to purge cache.

(This may be a bit naive to specify but don't forget to have the same changes of your config.php on your proxy^^)

Comment: This partially works, as the changing of the ROOT location to use the custom domain works and I can see the maintenance page.

All the links to the files and sub-pages use `http://custom-domain-name.com`

When we would like it as `http://domain-name.com/moodle`

And the same occurs for all resource files (css, js)

Comment: have you also changed the $CFG->dataroot below?
Beside for the css and js, if may also be because you're using the jscache option (same file) and / or the developer mode (in admin panel)
Edit : Try to check the commented options in the config.php: You can also specify the dirroot but also force the themedir to force css/js files of your theme.